# Python: Try/Except

Tags: python-3.x

I want this too keep looping until a the correct name of the file is entered. For instance if I have a file called test.txt, then I want the question to loop until the right name is found. Is there anyway to do this?

```
def validate():
    file = ""
    flag = True
    while flag:
        try:
            file = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
            # If I leave false then it will quit the loop even if the file name 
            # does not exist. I only want it to exit once the correct file name 
            # is entered. Note the txt file will be created by the user so it
            # can always change.
            flag = False
        except FileNotFoundError:
            flag = True
    return file
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to use [`path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

```
import os

def validate():
    while True: #loop until the inputed filename is an existing file
        filename = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
        if os.path.isfile(filename): #filename refers to a file that exists and is not a folder
             return filename
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work? Actually open the file to trigger the exception

```
def validate():
    file = ""
    flag = True
    while flag:
        try:
            file = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
            with open(file) as fh:
                # do something with fh if you want
            flag = False
        except FileNotFoundError:
            flag = True
    return file
```

[Here's](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) more information about reading and writing files in python

Comment: can you explain what that extra line does?

Comment: @novicecoder the extra line opens the file. If it succeeds, it will put the file handle into `fh`, which you can use to read data from the file, write data to the file, etc. I edited my post with a link to the docs for more information.

Comment: so the fh is just a variable name that contains the open file?

Comment: @novicecoder indeed, it is a file object with its own methods for interacting with your opened file. For instance, `fh.readLines()` will output all the lines in your opened file.